# Help understanding equation with $\nabla_\hat{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following defined:

$\hat{x} \leftarrow \epsilon x + (1-\epsilon)\tilde{x}$

and then this:

$\lambda(||\nabla_\hat{x}D_w(\hat{x})||_2-1)^2$

Now this is something I have to implement into a computer program, and I think I've got most of it, with the exception of $\nabla_\hat{x}$

All of the different x are vectors

Could someone please help me understand what it means?
Thank you in advance!

**Edit for clarifications:**

- I'm implementing a Wasserstein GAN from the following paper: (https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00028). Section 4, page 4, equation 3 contains the equation in question
- $D_w$ is a neural network ( The discriminator in a GAN )
- The second equation is something the authors of the paper have called *Gradient Penalty* and is supposed to be added to the calculated loss used to train the algorithm.

Comment: What is w in that expression?

Comment: Would you be so kind to give some context? What is the general meaning of the 2nd equation, and what do you mean by implementing a computer program? Do you intend to, for example, solve a differential equation, or calculate the value of some known expression?

Comment: Edited question to clarify :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linear Algebra the operator in question is called the Del operator, $\nabla$ , and is defined such that:

$\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\mathbf{k}$.

The subscript used in your equation is $\hat{x}$, but what is the vector in question. From what I can understand you have del acting on this function $D_{w}(\hat{x})$ but the subscript might be restricting or changing what coordinate system Del is acting in.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you - this definitely helps!